# How to count a specific tags ex. <li> tag or <p> tag

Tags: php, html, regex

I want to use php to count every `li` tag inside my html code so I can know if there is missing closeing tag or not (`if the count of opening tags != the count of closing tags`)

Is it possible using **php regex**?

Here is my first html code:

```
<ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea  <!-- closing tag is missing -->
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

And what about `if the count of opening tags == the count of closing tags`, but there is mistake in the form itself:

```
<ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    </li>  <!-- opening tag is missing -->
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Tea  <!-- closing tag is missing -->
</ul>
```

Finally, is there more efficient way using php to do that task other than this way of thinking how to solve the problem

Comment: As said many many times before, I think you should not parse html with regex.

Comment: If you want to diagnose possibly invalid HTML, maybe Tidy can help you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.diagnose.php

Comment: @KaarelKont-Kontson That's why I mentioned: the note: Finally, .....

Comment: IMHO: it´s not an invalid html.. it´s only non conform xhtml format

Comment: Why don't you parse it as xml and check validation? with XMLReader?
html is xml struct.
I'm not php programmer what you can see this example and test it:
[example](http://php.net/manual/en/xmlreader.isvalid.php)

Comment: Note: I'm grabbing that HTML code from database, so I need it as it is as I can, only strip tags which is not closed, and sure that should be using PHP

Answer (score 1):

first of all i think it´s better to give that  tag an id.

Html

```
<ul id="drinks">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea  //closing tag is missing
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

the php way

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $xml = $str->asXML();  // $str is your html string
    $doc->loadXML($xml);
    $bar_count = $doc->getElementsByTagName("ul")->length;
    echo $bar_count;
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    $elem = new SimpleXMLElement($str); // $str is your html string
    foreach ($elem as $ul) {
        printf("%s has got %d children.\n", $ul['id'], $ul->count());
    }
?>
```

or

```
<?php
   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($str); // $str is your html string
   echo $DOM->getElementsByTagName('ul')->length;
?>
```

the javascript way is something like this:

```
function drinksCount(){
    return document.getElementById("drinks").childNodes.length;
}
```

the anonymus way with jquery is

```
function drinksCount(){
    return $("ul li").children().length;    
}
```

with a called id eq

```
function drinksCount(){
    return $("#drinks li").children().length;    
}
```

if you want to go the regex way.. in case of non conform xhtml.. try to count leading

```
/<td>/gm
```

hope it helps...

Comment: He asked for php soution.

Comment: i implied he asked for a regex.. and i want to show alternatives..

Comment: @AlexTape Thanks for giving me different methods. I tried Dom method and I got `DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : li in Entity, line: ...` how can I catch that and delete that extra li tag?

Comment: @Dvir i'm no guru...however if op asks for regex solution when dealing with dom, then it has to be expected that a domdoc related answer will come up...op has to determine if regex is suitable, as sometimes regex is easier/faster/better than using domdoc. everything has weight, but it doesnt mean domdoc is not the right answer.

Comment: @usama, you can suppress errors by prefixing call with @ ie `@DOMDocument::loadHTML()`. if error is inconsequential suppress it and move on

Comment: @usama mabye you can mark my answer as useful if it helped you? gwillie answered your second question already.. :)

Comment: @AlexTape sure I will, but can't get rid the extra li tag, I keep trying but I only getting the warning message. How can I do so?

Comment: why you want to count the li´s ?